# Markup Schema for boat reservation does not work

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to create email with Markup for BOAT reservation
I've tested with sample code for BUS reservation schema and it works
but the boat schema is not working or I am not choosing right attributes please guide.

```
 <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BoatReservation">
  <meta itemprop="reservationId" content="%%=v(@reservation_number)=%%">
  <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed">
  <div itemprop="underName" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="%%=v(@full_name)=%%">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BoatTrip">
    <meta itemprop="Name" content="%%=v(@ship_name)=%%">
    </div>
    <div itemprop="rentalCompany" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="%%=v(@ship_name)=%%">
    </div>

  <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2027-08-05T16:00:00-07:00">
  <meta itemprop="modifyReservationUrl" content="%%=v(@ModifyReservationURL)=%%">
<meta itemprop="price" content="%%=v(@Price)=%%">
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="%%=v(@Currency)=%%">
</div>
```

> BUSTRIP Schema works but only concern it has bus symbol for stops. (attached screenshot)

[bus symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7VFx.png)
Thanks in advance.